# How to fix Remote OS Command Injection security issue in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I run ZAP scanner in my application, it gave one high priority issue as:

> High (Medium) Remote OS Command Injection
>
> Description
>
> Attack technique used for unauthorized execution of operating system
>   commands. This attack is possible when an application accepts
>   untrusted input to build operating system commands in an insecure
>   manner involving improper data sanitization, and/or improper calling
>   of external programs.
>
> ```
> URL
> ```
>
> http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/users/5
>
> ```
>     Parameter
> ```
>
> user[time_zone]
>
> ```
>     Attack
> ```
>
> Pacific Time (US & Canada)"&sleep 5s&"
>
> ```
> URL
> ```
>
> http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/users/5
>
> ```
>     Parameter
> ```
>
> user[designations]
>
> ```
>     Attack
> ```
>
> tester"&sleep 5s&"
>
> ```
> URL
> ```
>
> http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/users/5
>
> ```
>     Parameter
> ```
>
> user[password]
>
> ```
>     Attack
> ```
>
> ;start-sleep -s 5

How to fix this type of issue?

Comment: Hard to say without more details. You're probably calling system ( or equivalent) with unsanitised parameters.

Comment: Actually it is an users show page. What kind of details you need?

Comment: well for starters you could try and find the offending bit of code. If not the only answer is 'sanitise your parameters'

Answer (score 0):

Check a different flavour of OS command injection - https://asecurityz.blogspot.in/2017/11/os-command-injection-through-other.html

Consider this while implementing your fix.